# Cannot install Virtualbox's Extension Pack 4.1.14

Tags: installation, virtualbox, updates

I've just updated my VirtualBox and cannot install the latest associative extension pack.

My Virtualbox version

[image]

My Extension Pack version

[image]

My error

[image]

Please help.

Comment: From what I can see, I would assume the pack is already installed.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg But when I call `Help - Update`, the application still announce me to download the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I luckily think of a work-around to this issue: trying to remove the old extension pack version before installing new one.

So I open VirtualBox Manager and go to `File - Preference - Extension Pack`, then select the old version and remove it. You know what, the same error appeared; so what I can say about the error I get when updating the extension pack is all CANNOT about removing old one.

So, I go to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` and rename the folder `ExtensionPacks` to `ExtensionPacks2`. Then, things go smoothly.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I get these errors too. Are you attempting to install this as a limited user or an admin?

I am able resolve this by logging out of my limited user account. Then logging in with an account that is a member of the `Local Administrators` group.

Then attempt to install the extension pack.

Good luck

Update: this is different from unsingthe `RunAs` Context menu item. You need to 'physicaly' logout of the limited user account

Comment: I have no luck with that. I have just retried it with `run as admin` and the error remains

Comment: See my update..

Comment: This is strange. I don't have such errors for previous updates. Just this version cause error. I don't wanna dick into the `local admin` group at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me ...

Run your Oracle VMbox as Admin and go to preference -> extension and import it it will work ..

if it is still not working uninstall old version of oracle VMbox and download latest and try again with compatible extension pack .